# How to transform a CURL query to OpenURI query with OATH

Tags: ruby, curl, oauth, nokogiri, open-uri

One of my projects returns token codes using an HTTP query so users easily can get and renew them if desired. I found one article where the author uses CURL queries to my host.

For example:

```
curl -k -H 'Authorization: Bearer SQ43OPLR79BIQQFN50PA6KI8MVJ77JT685V0S9TTRNNA6RO41DTA6FK7NR1H466C' -H 'User-Agent: api-test-agent' https://api.hh.ru/employers/2062418
```

It works and returns a JSON object.

I need an OpenURI-based query. How can I change this CURL command to a simple OpenURI call?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While you'll probably get answers, remember that Stack Overflow is not a "convert this code to something else for me" site. Instead, you are supposed to do the research and put in the effort to do the conversion, then, when you've run into a specific problem ask about that particular thing. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" will help. Also, your question is very difficult to understand. Please take time to read it carefully as others around the world should be able to make sense from it.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent request through open-uri is:

```
require 'open-uri'

puts open('https://api.hh.ru/employers/2062418',
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer SQ43OPLR79BIQQFN50PA6KI8MVJ77JT685V0S9TTRNNA6RO41DTA6FK7NR1H466C',
          'User-Agent' => 'api-test-agent'
          ).read
```

Comment: Peris YOU SUPER! SUPER! SUPER!

Comment: Oh NO!!!
/var/www/html/api/tools.rb:30:in `getUrlAuth': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)

Comment: The issue seems to be that you're calling `getUrlAuth` method with an argument when it doesn't expect one, but that's not related to the code above though

Comment: I fix one error. But then get another. Here it is.
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/header.rb:18:in `block in initialize_http_header': undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: First argument not empty, I cheked. Who's NIL?

Comment: Sure I can use system curl and get result and parse it as JSON. But hope there is more comfortable way.......